# How to configure reports at Jenkins?

Tags: testing, jenkins, report, automated-tests, jenkins-plugins

I am new at Jenkins.
I want to configure my Jenkins to present some pretty UI reports after my tests are run. I installed the HTML publisher plugin. Now I have to fill the following information:

```
html directory to archive 
index pages 
report title
```

What information I need to give here?
I gave the path of a directory "Reports" in "html directory to archive ". But now after the build is run, the HTML report link gives error: HTTP ERROR 404. Reason: not found
What path do I need to give in archive field. If there is a file to be created, then how to create a file/folder at Jenkins

Comment: If there is any other simpler way to present the report, that suggestion is welcome too.
I use mercurial, bitbucket - I write scripts in Python and shell script

Answer (score 0):

If you're using one of the popular test suites supported by the xUnit plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin), then you can feed your test output reports to the plugin and produce a fancy page that will display all kinds of information about your results.

You can also define your own style sheets using something like the WebUI plugin (https://github.com/versionone/webui-plugin) if you want to customize the way the test output page looks.